# Change block of code based on external config file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In PHP, i would have a config file that says something like `$account = 'on'` and then throughout my project, i would have if else based on whether that variable equaled on or off.

Now im trying to do something similar in RoR. However, i am pretty new to RoR and considering all the features and implementations rails have, im thinking there has to be a method to basically take a block of code, wrap it in something that says if on, display, if not, dont.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Put this in an initializer
@config = YAML::Load(open([Rails.root, "config/options.yml"].join("/")))

if @config[:account] == "on"
   # do this...
else
   # do this...
end
```

Comment: Yes exactly. Except I want to declare config in only one spot, and then be able to access it throughout the entire project

Comment: I saw somewhere that i can declare a variable inside a yaml file. Lets say i have `account: on` . In my view or controller or whatever, how would i say "if account is on, do this, else, this"?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [nifty-generators](https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators)(config generator) or [configatron](https://github.com/markbates/configatron) and chose one which better fits your needs and looks more elegant to you.